# Gradle build jar cannot find dependency at run time

Tags: java, gradle, json-simple

I have below build.gradle file in which I have included json-simple dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
 
dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'src.main.java.demo.Hello'
    )
  }
}
```

I have below class which uses json-simple:

```
package src.main.java.demo;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class Hello{
    public String hello(){
        try{String jsonString="{\"first\":\"Hello\",\"second\":\"world\"}";
        JSONParser jspa=new JSONParser();
        JSONObject job=(JSONObject)jspa.parse(jsonString);
        return (String)job.get("first");    }
        catch(Exception e){
            return "";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new Hello().hello());    
    } 
}
```

The project builds successfully but on running the created jar file of project, it says it cannot find `JSONParser and JSONObject`. It means that these dependencies are not added at runtime. What should I do to add them to the classpath?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a fat jar. Change your build gradle like this

```
jar {
   manifest { 
      attributes "Main-Class": "src.main.java.demo.Hello"
   }  

  from {
     configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}        
   }
}
```

for older Gradle you should use this

```
from {
configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

Comment: thank You very much brother, it is working. But could you please tell what it is exactly doing?

Comment: With the additional configuration you are creating one big jar which contains all the class files not only from your project but also from the dependencies. In your first attemp you had only your own jar without dependencies.

Comment: One more thing, the config you provided is making fat jar of even junit. But i want fat jar of json-simple only. Can we provide its name inside your configuration?

Comment: if you want to change the name of the archive you can add following line to jar task. I guess it should work   as in the same level of manifest and from "baseName 'abc'"